# Using list for dynamic structure allocation

Tags: c++, arrays, list, structure

This is my first time here!

I want to do something simple but for the life of me I can't seem to figure it out...

I am reading a file containing data. Within that data, I have specific tags that are meaningful to me. I call them 'tags' but in the file, it's a string of text representing something. I need to extract these tags along with two other strings following that each tags found. The tag and data will be stored in a structure that is to be created dynamically because I don't know how many tags I will extract. So I cannot create a structure with, like, 100 elements, because I may only need 50 just like I can require 150.

Basically, the file is read continuously in a loop until EOF is encountered. As the file is parsed, when a tag is found, the tag name and associated following two strings are read properly. Then I need to store them in the structure. Once extracted, the loop restarts and repeats the tag and data extraction all the way to the end. Once the entire file is read and all tags have been extracted in a dynamic structure, all this data will be dumped to a file and the memory allocated dynamically can then be flushed.

I was told to use a list but I can't seem to figure-out how to make it work. Ideally, a functional piece of code would be of great help. I am doing this in C++ (C is fine).

Example of something I tried and it's not compiling:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    char Tag[30];
    char String1[30];
    char String2[30];
};

int Counter;

std:list<MyStruct> MyList;

MyStruct Data;

std:list<MyStruct>::iterator it;


for( Counter = 0; Counter < 5; Counter++)
{
    strcpy( Data.Tag, "Tag" );
    strcpy( Data.String1, "String1" );
    strcpy( Data.String2, "String2" );

    MyList.push_back(Data);
}

it = MyList.begin();
while (it != MyList.end())
{
    cout << "Tag: " << it->Tag << "First: " << it->String1 << "Second: " << it->String2 << endl;
    it++;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why on earth are you using `strcpy` for this? Why `char[]` instead of `std::string`? Why are all of your variable names Capitalized?

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are facing? Are you stuck on reading the file? `std::list::push_back()` is handling your dynamic allocation already.

Comment: Which error have you when you compile your code ? I agree with 3Dave comment for Capitalized names. For std::string, continue to use char[] and when your issue is solved replaced char[] by std::string.

Comment: If you need a dynamic array, use `std::vector` by default. It has the same interface as `std::list`, but for most operations, it has better performance because of how it's implemented. `std::list` is really only needed for a few special situations, like when you need stable iterators.

Answer (score 1):

### Instead of std:list use std::list

Like this:

```cpp
     #include <iostream>
    #include <list>
    #include <cstring>

    struct MyStruct
    {
        char Tag[30];
        char String1[30];
        char String2[30];
    };
    void something(){

        int Counter;

        std::list<MyStruct> MyList;

        MyStruct Data;

        std::list<MyStruct>::iterator it;


        for( Counter = 0; Counter < 5; Counter++)
        {
            strcpy( Data.Tag, "Tag" );
            strcpy( Data.String1, "String1" );
            strcpy( Data.String2, "String2" );

            MyList.push_back(Data);
        }

        it = MyList.begin();
        while (it != MyList.end())
        {
            std::cout << "Tag: " << it->Tag << "First: " << it->String1 << "Second: " << it->String2 << std::endl;
            it++;
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of list try to use vector, the *vector* has the ability to allocate more memory if needed.

[std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

> The storage of the vector is handled automatically, being expanded and
>   contracted as needed. Vectors usually occupy more space than static
>   arrays, because more memory is allocated to handle future growth. This
>   way a vector does not need to reallocate each time an element is
>   inserted, but only when the additional memory is exhausted. The total
>   amount of allocated memory can be queried using capacity() function.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    // Create a vector containing integers
    std::vector<int> v = {7, 5, 16, 8};

    // Add two more integers to vector
    v.push_back(25);
    v.push_back(13);

    // Iterate and print values of vector
    for(int n : v) {
        std::cout << n << '\n';
    }
}
```

P.S

If you also don't know the lengths of the Tag,String1,String2 values try to replace the *MyStruct* variables to string type (instead of the char).